# How to deploy artifact to aws s3 using github workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, cloud, github-actions

I have two workflows one for ci and one for cd. The job is to deploy a static website to and s3 bucket. It should deploy the files within the artifact generated from the ci. I want to download the artifact and unzip to a directory inside my repository, this will then allow my cd to upload the files inside the www directory to s3 for static web hosting.

Here is the ci script

```html
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 12.8
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: npm dependencies
      run: npm install     
    - name: run
      run: npm run build --if-present
    - name: Archive production artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
          name: dist-without-markdown
          path: |
            www
```

Here is the cd script.

```html
name: cd

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["ci"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
      env:
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: udagram-frontend-sm
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        SOURCE_DIR: 'www'      # optional: defaults to entire repository
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another action to download the artifact.

```
name: cd

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["ci"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build # to ensure deploy run after build jobs
    steps:
    # the deploy step won't need checkout source code again.
    # the download-artifact action can auto unzip artifact to the target folder. 
    - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: dist-without-markdown
        path: www
    - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
      env:
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: udagram-frontend-sm
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        SOURCE_DIR: 'www'      # optional: defaults to entire repository
```

Comment: Doesn’t work. It download to the workflow server. I clearly state what I want and this doesn’t do it

Comment: Combine with the s3-sync-action action, you should be able to upload the file in workflow server to s3 right?

Comment: No. I want to download the zip to the repo. Unzip then upload. You can’t upload a zip to run a static web site

Comment: the github action ubuntu environment already installed unzip command, you can simply add a step that calls unzip file.zip to unzip your bundle and then upload to s3.
ref: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md

Comment: would you mind clarifying a bit more about **download the zip to the repo**, since your repo doesn't have any file storage unless you want to commit those files to your GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes I want to commit them to the repo

Comment: correct me if I missed something, that likely will cause some other issues. 
let said the github action committed those files to the repo, then the new commit (with unzipped files) will trigger your ci workflow to generate a new bundle, and also create more commits.

Comment: Good point that is, but I can change the trigger

Comment: I updated my answer to include more details on how download-artifact fit into the workflow. actually the download-artifact action will auto unzip to the target folder, you can simply upload it to s3.

Comment: I assume part of the reason you want to commit the files to the repo is that ci and cd are two different workflows and they can't share artifacts. 

but generally committing the generated build files into the repo is not a good practice, can consider the release tag and upload the build bundle as release assets to archive the ci/cd process.